Inverse of gamma function with R
With gamma() in R you get output 24 from input 5.
How can I make inverse function which can get output 5 from input 24?
>gamma(5)
24

I found [invgamma] package, but I can’t understand if it is appropriate one nor how to use it…

The invgamma package is for the inverse gamma distribution, rather than inverting the gamma function.

Use uniroot to find the root of gamma(x) - a, where a is your number.
invgamma <- function(a, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) {
  uniroot(\(x) gamma(x) - a, c(1, 1e2), extendInt = "upX", tol = tol)
}

invgamma(24)$root
#> [1] 5

invgamma(24)
#> $root
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $f.root
#> [1] -5.207212e-11
#> 
#> $iter
#> [1] 19
#> 
#> $init.it
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $estim.prec
#> [1] 7.450582e-09

Created on 2024-09-29 with reprex v2.1.0
You can vectorize this function.
igamma <- Vectorize(invgamma, "a")
igamma(c(6, 24, 120)) |> t()
#>      root f.root        iter init.it estim.prec  
#> [1,] 4    -2.771117e-13 17   NA      7.450582e-09
#> [2,] 5    -5.207212e-11 19   NA      7.450582e-09
#> [3,] 6    2.727063e-11  18   NA      7.450583e-09

Created on 2024-09-29 with reprex v2.1.0

Below are two fully vectorized options using Newton-Raphson. The first is in base R. The second is a bit faster but requires the lamW package. Both take less than a second to calculate 1M inverses.
Depending on the usage, you may want additional checks, such as handling NA or nulls.
Note that x = gamma(y) has a minimum (x = 0.885603194410889) at y = 1.46163214496836 and approaches Inf as y approaches 0 and Inf, so there are two positive solutions to x = gamma(y) for x > 0.885603194410889. The functions below provide the value of y for y > 1.46163214496836 (the "principal branch").

Base R
This Q&A provides a decent initial approximation to begin the Newton-Raphson iterations.
gammainv <- function(x) {
  i <- 1:length(x)
  out <- numeric(length(x))
  out[b <- (x < 0.885603194410889)] <- NA # minimum of gamma function
  i <- i[!b]
  x <- x[i]
  out[i[b <- (x == 1)]] <- 2 # principal branch
  i <- i[!b]
  x <- x[!b]
  x <- log(x)
  # initial estimate
  m <- x/log1p(x) + 1
  k <- (lgamma(m) - x)/log(m)
  y <- m - k - 1 + (x - lgamma(m - k))/log(m - k)
  y[y < 1.46163214496836] <- 1.5 # principal branch
  # Newton-Raphson
  while (length(i)) {
    y0 <- y
    y <- y - (lgamma(y) - x)/digamma(y)
    b <- which(abs(y - y0) < 1e-13)
    if (length(b)) {
      out[i[b]] <- y[b]
      y <- y[-b]
      i <- i[-b]
      x <- x[-b]
    }
  }
  out
}

Testing:
1e6 - gamma(x <- gammainv(1e6))
#> [1] 2.211891e-09
dput(gamma(x))
#> 999999.999999998

gammainv(cumprod(1:170))
#>   [1]   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
#>  [19]  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37
#>  [37]  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
#>  [55]  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73
#>  [73]  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91
#>  [91]  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109
#> [109] 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127
#> [127] 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145
#> [145] 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163
#> [163] 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171

x <- exp(runif(1e6, log(0.885603194410889), 709))
system.time(y <- gammainv(x))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.85    0.03    0.87
all.equal(x, gamma(y))
#> [1] TRUE


lamW
Additional speed using the Lambert W function, which provides a better initial approximation.
library(lamW)

gammainv <- function(x) {
  i <- 1:length(x)
  out <- numeric(length(x))
  out[b <- (x < 0.885603194410889)] <- NA # minimum of gamma function
  i <- i[!b]
  logsqrt2pi <- log(2*pi)/2
  x <- pmax(x, exp(logsqrt2pi - 1))
  x <- log(x[i])
  y <- exp(lambertW0((x - logsqrt2pi)/exp(1)) + 1) + 0.5
  # Newton-Raphson
  while (length(i)) {
    y0 <- y
    y <- y - (lgamma(y) - x)/digamma(y)
    b <- which(abs(y - y0) < 1e-13)
    if (length(b)) {
      out[i[b]] <- y[b]
      y <- y[-b]
      i <- i[-b]
      x <- x[-b]
    }
  }
  out
}

Testing
1e6 - gamma(y <- gammainv(1e6))
#> [1] 4.074536e-09
dput(gamma(y))
#> 999999.999999996

gammainv(cumprod(1:170))
#>   [1]   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
#>  [19]  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37
#>  [37]  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
#>  [55]  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73
#>  [73]  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91
#>  [91]  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109
#> [109] 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127
#> [127] 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145
#> [145] 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163
#> [163] 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171

x <- exp(runif(1e6, log(0.885603194410889), 709))
system.time(y <- gammainv(x))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.73    0.05    0.56
all.equal(x, gamma(y))
#> [1] TRUE


interesting and efficient implementation of inverse Gamma, +1!. Do you have any algorithmic reference about the code? Better to show it in the solution in case other wonder about how/why it works.

I added a couple links that discuss the initial approximations.

That looks great, thanks for adding the references.
